# Bootstrap masonry layout - with maintain scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a conundrum and can't seem to work out the answer.

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and masonry layout as per their suggestion here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/ and it works great.

I also need to use a maintain scroll script. The issue is that maintain scroll doesn't work when using BS masonry. Take out BS masonry and maintain scroll works as expected.

Here's my maintainscroll script - any ideas would be great - thanks in advance.

```
                window.onload = function() {
                var scrollpos = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
                if (scrollpos) window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);                   
                };          
                window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
                };
```

Comment: Masonry initialization can only happen when the document is already loaded (it needs to know element dimensions, so their styling needs to apply already, images need to have loaded) - so you are most likely simply trying to jump too early here. The re-arranging of the element layout is not complete at this point, and so the position you are jumping to, is simply the wrong one at that time. I suppose you will probably have to bind this to the `layoutComplete` event, https://masonry.desandro.com/events.html#layoutcomplete

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. - working on that basis, I've tweaked the script (and changed to vanilla JS too.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked script to fire after page load is complete - worked a treat - thanks CBroe for the heads up.

```
                window.onload = function() {
                var scrollpos = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
                if (scrollpos) window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);                   
                };          
                window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
                };
```